# Not able register hapi-cron-job plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, hapi.js

I am trying to schedule cronjobs which will run at specified time, i am using `hapi-cron-job` of `hapi`, when i try to register the plugin, i am getting below error.

```
[1] "plugin.register" must be of type function
    at Object.exports.apply (D:\my_dir\Repositories\repo-cronjobs\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\config.js:19:15)
    at internals.Server.register (D:\my_dir\Repositories\repo-cronjobs\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\server.js:454:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Please find the configuration while registering the plugin.

server.js

```
  const { plugins } = require('./register/index');

  await server
    .register(plugins)
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Plugin registeration failed!');
      console.error(err);
    });
```

index.js

```
module.exports.plugins = [
  // I have here other pluguns, passing this array for registration in server.js 
  require("./hapi-cron-job-plugin")
];
```

hapi-cron-job-plugin.js

```
const hapiCronJob = require('hapi-cron-job')
const plugin = {
  register: require('hapi-cron-job'),
  options: {
    jobs: [
      {
        name: "diplay time",
        enabled: true,
        immediate: true,
        schedule: "every 1 s",
        execute: alertSystemAdminAndDispatcher,
        environments: ['development', 'staging']
      }
    ],
  }
}

module.exports = plugin;
```

nodeJS version: `v14.17.3`

Hapi-cron-job: `"hapi-cron-job": "^2.0.1"`

Comment: Any help from anyone?

Comment: Waiting for the response, anyone?

Comment: The `hapi-cron-job` package is seriously old (6 years since the last update). Are you sure it's compatible with the version of Hapi you're using?

Comment: @Phil
Thank you for your response, I am already using this package in one of my other microservice and it is working fine there, I am working on segregating some services (all cronjobs)  as a separate `microservice` and trying to configure `hap-cron-job` as a cronjob service in the new one and facing this issue while configuration.
Hapi.js version in both the microservices:  `16.1.1`